# Can't run sudo apt update

Tags: apt, updates

Problem

```
Hit:1 https://apt.corretto.aws stable InRelease                                                                                 
Hit:2 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                       
Hit:3 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                               
Hit:4 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                                             
Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                    
Hit:7 http://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/jammy pgadmin4 InRelease                                               
Ign:8 http://packages.azlux.fr/debian jammy InRelease                                                                           
Err:9 http://packages.azlux.fr/debian jammy Release                                                                             
  404  Not Found [IP: 37.58.181.100 80]
Hit:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                        
Hit:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                     
Reading package lists... Done                                                
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/(http could not be found.
N: Is the package apt-transport-(http installed?
E: The repository 'http://packages.azlux.fr/debian jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

tried

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 1 510 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 apt-transport-https all 2.4.11 [1 510 B]
Fetched 1 510 B in 0s (5 195 B/s)                   
(Reading database ... 241018 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apt-transport-https_2.4.11_all.deb ...
Unpacking apt-transport-https (2.4.11) over (2.4.11) ...
Setting up apt-transport-https (2.4.11) ...
```

ping 37.58.181.100 works

```
PING 37.58.181.100 (37.58.181.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 37.58.181.100: icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=67.9 ms
64 bytes from 37.58.181.100: icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=68.3 ms
64 bytes from 37.58.181.100: icmp_seq=3 ttl=51 time=66.2 ms
```

curl

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.25.4</center>
</body>
</html>
```

What should or can i do to fix?

Comment: You obviously can run `apt update`, otherwise you wouldn't get that output. Your problem is that you added a ppa to your software sources which doesn't support your version of Ubuntu. Remove this ppa from your system.

Comment: Consider searching the site before posting questions; this has been asked and answered dozens of times already.

Comment: @OrganicMarble, to be fair, as they can´t fix this themselves they probably don´t realise what is the actual error message: the "E:" lines are "Errors" and you can copy them to Google, Bing, whatever, or AskUbuntu search to try and find solutions. It looks like Azlux.fr domain removed that repos, or had a transient error that removed it, or you updated and they never had that version. You could check in with Azlux.fr and see if they just have an error. Might work again later if they're rebuilding the site after an error, for example.

Comment: @lldus why would I "check in" about some ppa I don't use?

Comment: Thank for answers!

Well, i had no idea that proplem was with ppa! 
Before asking question i had been googling for 4-5 hours.